# Как не возвращать null?

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который возвращает объект, если он имеется в списке. Как избавиться от возвращения null, если объектов в списке нет?

Допустим:

```
public SomeObject ReturnSomeObject(){
    return (SomeObjectList.Count > 0) ? SomeObjectList[0] : null;
}
```

Comment: где-то читал, что просто возвращать null нехорошо, поскольку постоянно приходится добавлять проверку на это. Но если требуется возвратить объект, которого нет в списке (потому что список пуст, например), что обычно делают в таких ситуациях? Может необходимо сначала проверить на наличие объекта, а потом только вызывать функцию для его возвращения или может еще какой есть способ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если не хочется возвращать `null`, то самым разумным будет генерировать исключение, что-нибудь вроде `ObjectNotFoundException()`.

Answer (score 2):

Поздравляю! Вы вышли на путь открытия т.н. "[типа-опции](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type)" ([option type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type)), который более развитые языки программирования (Scala, F#, Ocaml, Haskell, и т.д.) используют уже давным давно. В C#, равно как и в Java, такого типа нет, но его легко сделать самостоятельно. Для начала, рекомендую вам прочитать мой ответ на вопрос "[Язык программирования без null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/10778/%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-null)", чтобы понять, что такое тип-опция. Затем переходите к статье "[Option type implementation in C#](http://litemedia.info/option-type-implementation-in-csharp)", в которой показано, как реализовать и применять этот тип в C#.

Answer (score 0):

Возвращать новый объект, например. Или хранить экземпляр, возвращаемый по умолчанию, в поле класса и возвращать его, если список пуст.

Comment: раньше проверяли на null,  а теперь придется проверять, не возвратили ли нам объект по умолчанию:)

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя просто не возвращать, нужно выбрать, что делать вместо этого. Хотя, как мне кажется, пространства для выбора и нет - только выбрасывать исключение

Answer (score 0):

В некоторых ситуациях может быть уместным использование паттерна ["Null Object"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) - возвращать объект подкласса (или как это лучше сделать в C#), который реализует операции класса пустыми - другими словами, NOP-реализацию. С этим паттерном, конечно, нужно быть осторожным и привлекать только при полной уверенности, что выгоды перевесят усложнение системы.

Comment: Вообще да, на этапе проектирования программы надо чётко понимать, как себя будет вести какой компонент и почему.